# Read JSON File with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Hey I'm trying to read data from a JSON File with jQuery. This is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myItems;

    $.getJSON('testData.json', function(data) {
        myItems = data.items;
        console.log(myItems);
    });
});
```

And that is the JSON File:

```
{"fname":"rafael","lname":"marques","age":"19"}
{"fname":"daniel","lname":"marques","age":"19"}
```

When I open my HTML Page in the Browser I can't see nothing in the Console.

Comment: I don't see you set anything to display. But since there is `console.log`, you can open the developer console to see the result.

Comment: JSON is supposed to contain a single object, not two. [Use JSONlint](http://jsonlint.org/) to validate it.

Comment: maybe opening the console? Press F12

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add comma after each object, wrap then with `[]` and enclosed them with an object with property `items` in json file so it will look like

```
{
    items: [
    {
        "fname": "rafael",
        "lname": "marques",
        "age": "19"},
    {
        "fname": "daniel",
        "lname": "marques",
        "age": "19"
    }]
}
```

then you should try for

```
$.each(data.items, function(key, val) {
   alert(val.fname);
   alert(val.lname);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
{"fname":"rafael","lname":"marques","age":"19"}
{"fname":"daniel","lname":"marques","age":"19"}
```

Isn't a correct json file. Add a comma between the lines or make it like this :

```
{items:[
    {"fname":"rafael","lname":"marques","age":"19"},
    {"fname":"daniel","lname":"marques","age":"19"}
]}
```

to comply with your apparent requirements.

But opening the console to look at errors would have solved this.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "items":[
        {
            "fname":"Asfahan",
            "lname":"Ahmad",
            "age":"25",
            "address":"bangalore"
        },
        {
            "fname":"Mohd",
            "lname":"Rehan",
            "age":"19",
            "address":"Tanda"
        }
    ]
}

save this json file with the name JSONData.json

` $.getJSON('JSONData.json',function(data){
                 $.each(data.items,function(key,value){
                     alert(value.fname);
                     alert(value.lname);
                     alert(value.age);
                     alert(value.address);
                 })`enter code here`
             })`
```