# how to make json file instead of static data in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a simple example in which I am taking static data on my script.

Here is my static data on **i18n_dict and i18n_dict2** . Can we make individual json files of every language  on our project.

Can someone explain how we do that and what changes are required in the code?

[Here is a Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/samosfator/yBM69/)

```
i18n_dict = {
    "Example 1": "teiän veen",
        "Example 2": "tei'än ve'en",
        "Example 3": "teiä vede",
        "Example 4": "teirän veren",
        "Example 5": "teilän velen",
        "Example 6": "teijjän vejen",
        "Example 7": "teidän veden",
        "Example 8": "teitän veten",
        "Example 9": "teiðän veðen",
        "Example 10": "teidhän vethen",
        "Dynamic Content": "Your browser window is %s x %s",
        "Ordered Dynamic Content": "%2$s is the height of your browser window, and %1$s is the width."
};
//Newly created object
i18n_dict2 = {
    "Example 1": "Пример первый",
        "Example 2": "Пример второй",
        "Example 3": "Пример третий",
        "Example 4": "Пример четвертый",
        "Example 5": "Пример пятый",
        "Example 6": "Пример шестой",
        "Example 7": "Пример седьмой",
        "Example 8": "Пример восьмой",
        "Example 9": "Пример девятый",
        "Example 10": "Пример десятый",
        "Dynamic Content": "Ваш браузер размером %s x %s",
        "Ordered Dynamic Content": "%2$s высота окна браузера, и %1$s это ширина."
};
```

Comment: What server language you are using?

Comment: it is static value(hard coded) please check fiddle.can we hardcoded value in json file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type='button' id='translate_button'  data-lang="fin" value='Internationalize!'>
<input type='button' id='translate_button2' data-lang="rus "value='Internationalize to Russian!'>
```

save the two jsons in fin.json and rus.json

```
$('button').click(function(){
     var lang=$(this).data('lang')+'.json';
     $.ajax({
                url: lang,
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                 var dict = $.parseJSON(data);
                 $.i18n.setDictionary(dict);
                 $('div#example1').text($.i18n._('Example 1'));
                  ..  ...........
             }
         });
});
```

Comment: can we make on this on fiddle

Comment: but we have to save the json files also to parse them.difficult

Comment: actually I am to confuse  can you make a simple program .and upload on dropbox

Comment: can i mail u these files??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41789/discussion-between-bhadra-and-user2648752)

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is an example:

 $.getJSON('i18nru.json', function(data) {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

[and here is the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936196/read-json-file-with-jquery)

Comment: how to make json file ..I open notepad save like abc.json is it correct?

Comment: save it as abc.json,that is correct.but check it should nt be abc.json.txt